# Share information between processes in foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, foreman

I have a foreman with Procfile with a few processes:

```
web: rails s
polling: rake polling:start
```

And both processes use a instance of a class with a class variable:

```
@poll = Poll.new
```

How can I share this `@poll` variable between proccesses? I want change attributes of one `@poll` will lead to change attributes of another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a small research I've understand that websocket standard is the best way